# Django filter data using field in another model connected via foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

I have two models; `Sets` and `Cards`. There are many cards in one set. I would like to get it so that I can filter the cards that are returned in my tables but the set code, which for the example below is `khc`.

I have manage to get it to work to an extent by adding `filter(set__code__exact="khc")` to the `Card.objects` but this does not allow the user to change that filtering on the web page.

I cannot seem to add a `code` filter to the `CardFilter`

**models.py**

```py
class Set(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...

class Card(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
    set = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Card')
```

**views.py**

```py
def cards_page(request):
    card_list = Card.objects.filter(set__code__exact="khc").order_by('name')
    card_filter = CardFilter(request.GET, queryset=card_list)
    card_list = card_filter.qs
```

**filters.py**

```py
class SetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    code = CharFilter(field_name='code', lookup_expr='iexact', label='', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Set Code', 'class': 'page-input', 'style': 'width: 150px;'}))
    name = CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains', label='', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name', 'class': 'page-input', 'style': 'width: 150px;'}))
    type = CharFilter(field_name='type', lookup_expr='icontains', label='', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type', 'class': 'page-input', 'style': 'width: 150px;'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = ''


class CardFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # doesnt work # code = CharFilter(field_name='set', lookup_expr='iexact', label='', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Set Code', 'class': 'page-input', 'style': 'width: 150px;'}))
    name = CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains', label='', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name', 'class': 'page-input', 'style': 'width: 150px;'}))
    type = CharFilter(field_name='type_line', lookup_expr='icontains', label='', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type', 'class': 'page-input', 'style': 'width: 150px;'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ''
```

**cards.html**

```html
<form method="get" class="" autocomplete="off">
    {{ card_filter.form.code }}
    {{ card_filter.form.name }}
    {{ card_filter.form.type }}
    <button class="page-btn-icon" type="submit">
    ...
```

**screenshot of filters:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was really simple when I manage to figure out how to do it.

I added `set_id__code` to the `field_name` variable in my `filters.py` file. `set_id` is the field that connects two tables together, followed by two underscores (__) and then the field name in the `Set` model I wanted to filter by.

```py
code = CharFilter(field_name='set_id__code', lookup_expr='iexact', label='', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Set Code', 'class': 'page-input', 'style': 'width: 150px;'}))
```